# How to prove a set does not span $P_4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the next set 
$$\{1-t^4,1+t+t^3+t^4,1+t-t^3+t^4,1-t^2 \}$$
Then I represent $P_4 = t^4(-c1+c2+c3)+t^3(c2-c3)+t^2(-c4)+t(c2+c3)+(c1+c2+c3+c4)$

After that I made a matrix and reduce it to:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&&0&&0&&0&&d-a\\0&&1&&0&&0&&b/2+d/2\\0&&0&&1&&0&&-b/2+d/2  \\0&&0&&0&&1&&-c\\0&&0&&0&&0&&-a-c+2d-e\end{bmatrix}$$

What I found is that I can represent $t^4,t^3,t^2,t$ but I don't have a way to represent the last term of $P_4$. How can I formally say that this set does not span $P_4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your list consists of four polynomials in $P_4$. But any spanning set of $P_4$ must contain at least $\dim(P_4)=5$ polynomials. Hence your list does not span $P_4$.